# Replacing Boot loader

Tags: bootloader

i want to replace my nexus 6 stock boot loader with the one i customized based on little kernel. but as long as i know there is a authentication chain from the very start of booting process in boot ROM to the start of android itself. so is it really possible for me to change the boot loader? cause it should break the chain.

Comment: Replace bootloader or recovery?

Comment: i want to replace the boot loader not the recovery image. i think it is called aboot.

Comment: A customized _bootloader_ based on a _kernel_? Please let us know what you want to achieve, and get your terms straight.

Comment: actually i don't have the bootloader yet. but with doing a little search i come up with little kernel which is Qualcomm project. as i know it's a partially open source project.

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwj9isi40J7RAhXLDiwKHX7oBw0QFggbMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.codeaurora.org%2Fblogs%2Flittle-kernel-based-android-bootloader&usg=AFQjCNEA4J42BSna8mSCc3f1V-a_kHQdQQ&sig2=T0t2O4QA2L0MVxfTnsLhMA&bvm=bv.142059868,d.bGg

Comment: I really appreciate if someone tell me is it possible or not to replace a nexus device boot loader